# On systems of axioms and fractals

Tags: analysis, logic, proof-verification, reference-request

DISCLAIMER: I am a physicist, not a mathematician. All this may be baloney.

Is there a way to connect the concept of fractals and that of systems of axioms? If so, it seems reasonable to identify fractals with only those logical systems that cannot be used also to count (i.e. to distinguish and order) natural numbers, because of the scale-invariance of fractals (i.e. no reference frame, in physics lingo). I'm just curious to read more about it.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific with what you're looking for. I don't really see what you mean by the identification of fractals with systems that cannot be used to count - the normal system can be used to count and we have fractals there.

Comment: I meant whether the rules to make a fractal (e.g. divide a segment in three equal parts and build an equilateral triangle on the central one) can be cast as axioms. And if so, whether these axioms can represent a logical system that can count. Because I have the naive (and largely unjustified) feeling that counting and self-similarity shouldn't go together.

Comment: I don't know about self-similarity aspects (seems too limiting to me), but there might be some things of interest that could be proved regarding the Hausdorff (packing, box, etc.) dimension of the set of true but not provable statements in various logical systems, when an appropriate metric structure is provided. See p. 18 [here](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~cristian/talks/selected/Google08Talk.pdf), or better yet, see [Is independence an exception?](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0096300394901589) if you have access.

Comment: @skyking: I am intrigued: what do you mean by the "normal system"?

Comment: @RobArthan The (axiom) system that is normally used in mathematics.